# Quarkus oidc allow multiple issuers

Tags: quarkus

I have a frontend that is running on angular and a backend that runs on spring boot. Both applications are connected to my azure-ad. My problem is that my frontend sends the jwt-tokens from the `iss: https://sts.windows.net/***` and my postman-client sends the jwt-tokens from the `iss:https://login.microsoftonline.com/***`. As a result I get this error from the quarkus-oidc library:
`Token verification has failed: Issuer (iss) claim value (https://login.microsoftonline.com/***) doesn't match expected value of https://sts.windows.net/***`.
Is there a way how I can configure my quarkus-app so that it can work with multiple issuers?